# What free static analysis tools are available for Rust?

Tags: gratis, static-analysis, rust

My need is to understand an existing Rust codebase.

I have the ability to see the module/trait/function hierarchy using rustdoc, and to quickly jump to refs and defs using VS Codium (privacy respecting VS Code), but would like a tool to help with things like generating and browsing the static call graph.

I've been searching and asking around for a couple of days without success, so asking: What free static analysis tools are available for Rust?

Answer (score 0):

Call Hierarchy is available in VSCode / VSCodium but only if you have rust-analyzer rather than RLS selected.

Using rust-analyzer you will have "Show Call Hierarchy" on the right-click menu.

If you are using RLS, as the Rust-client: Engine setting change it to rust-analyzer by typing Ctrl-, to get to settings, then type 'Rust' to filter the list and scroll to 'Rust-client: Engine' and choose 'rust-analyzer'. You will also need to close and re-open the workspace.

Comment: unfortunately the call hierarchy feature has never worked on VSCode with rust-analyzer, I really hope that it lands one day

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: ah, looks like it just doesn't work with generics or trait implementations